# PHP Automaticly log off users in session

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have an array with multiple users logged in. I want to log off the user that has been inactive for XX time.

Let me explain the situation. I have 1 pc where people can start and stop their tasks. I store their id so they can switch between the active users to stop, start and see information about their tasks very fast. Sometimes it happens that alot of people using only this pc to start their task and continue in another workspace, so the list with active users will grow fast while the other people have to search between the list with active users to find their own user id.

User ID list:

[image]

4700, 7100 and 2526 are the user id's that are logged in/active.

This is the array from my session:

```
'timestamp' => 
    array (size=3)
      4700 => int 1557473018
      7100 => int 1557472637
      2526 => int 1557473020
```

I found alot of user log off scripts, but everything is based on 1 user.

It is working with PHP, but I want it to work automaticly with javascript

Something like this I already tried.

```
  <script language='javascript'>
  var timeout = 60 * 1000; // 10 seconds  

  var lastAction = <?php echo isset($_SESSION['timestamp']) ? $_SESSION['timestamp'] : time();?>;
  var timer = function(){
     return setInterval(function(){
        var now = new Date();
        if (typeof lastAction !=='undefined' ){
          if(now.getTime() - lastAction >= timeout ){
             alert('have been logged out');
             <?php afmelden($Ids); ?>
          }
        }
      }, 1000) // repeat every 1 second;
  }
  window.onmousemove = function(e){
   clearInterval(timer);
   timer();   
  }
  window.onclick= function(e){
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer();
  }

  // and make initial call
  timer();
</script>
```

Comment: Ok. So what went wrong with what you tried?

Comment: @ADyson I have it working in PHP. When you refresh the page, it will check for inactive users. I want to make it automaticly but I don't know how... The script up here is giving me the alert non stop, even when I set the timer on 24 hours.

Comment: One obvious problem could be that PHP's [time()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns the time in **seconds** while JavaScript's [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns the time in **milliseconds** ... If you'd logged the values being generated into your console you might have noticed this large discrepancy?

Comment: I see the difference. PHP Time() is: 1557739523
Javascript getTime() is: 1557739523400

Comment: ok so hopefully you now realise how you could fix that?

Comment: Got it working! thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

If you have many active users, polling the server to database might cause a lot of traffic. The best solution I can think of here is adding the timestamp to the remember me token. For this example, I will use [JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt).

When you are logging a user in, create your token to hold what ever information you need:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['ssid'] = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode(array(
    'exp' => 1557738566 // Your expiration time from the DB
    'uid' => 1 // User ID the account is using
    'obj' => array() // Anything else you want to store in cache
));
```

We now need to send the request to the server to see any changes.

```
( ( $ ) => {
    var timer = () => {
        setInterval( () => {
            $.get( '/your/route' ).done( ( resp ) => {
                // resp will hold time left, current uid and any other
            } );
        }, 1000 );
    }
} )( JQuery );
```

Simple usage of the server could be:

```
session_start();
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(isset($_SESSION['ssid'])) {
    try {
        // TODO: Check the exp and log user out if expired
        die(json_encode(\Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode($_SESSION['ssid'], array())));
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        // bearer was invalid or expired - log them out
    }

    return;
}

// Redirect them to login
```

If you need to ever update your time, based of a user action, you can update the time in the token, and if necessary, the DB.

**Thoughts:**

> I only say it this way because having an open route like `afmelden($Ids)` doesn't stop someone directly accessing that route in their browser with any ID they want unless that route has RBAC.